# How to get Json key and value with iterator in andorid

Tags: android, json

How to get this Json key and value from the web. This is my code, but I can't get this from the second iteration. can some one help me to do this.

Json Response :

```
    "attributes": [
  {
    "main_id": "3",
    "Color": [
      {
        "id": "60",
        "text": "46( +$0.00)"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "main_id": "21",
    "dede": [
      {
        "id": "73",
        "text": "baba( +$0.00)"
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

This is my android code to parse the values :

```
JSONArray jsonArrayAttributes = jsonObj.getJSONArray("attributes");
    for (int i = 0; i < jsonArrayAttributes.length(); i++) {

        JSONObject jsonObject1 = jsonArrayAttributes.getJSONObject(i);
        Iterator iteratorKey = jsonObject1.keys();
        String strAttrId = (String) iteratorKey.next();
        String strAttrName = (String) iteratorKey.next();

        JSONArray jsonArrayName = jsonObject1.getJSONArray(strAttrName);

        for (int j = 0; j < jsonArrayName.length(); j++) {
            JSONObject jsonObjName = jsonArrayName.getJSONObject(j);
        }
    }
```

Comment: I can't achieve using this JSON response. I changed the response accordingly.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to change your code little bit like

```
JSONArray jsonArrayAttributes = jsonObj.getJSONArray("attributes");

        for (int i = 0; i < jsonArrayAttributes.length(); i++) {

            JSONObject jsonObject1 = jsonArrayAttributes.getJSONObject(i);
            Iterator it = jsonObject1.keys();

            boolean arrFlag = false;
            while (it.hasNext()) {
                String key = (String) it.next();
                if (!arrFlag) {
                    String value = jsonObject1.getString(key);
                    Log.i("Key:Value", "" + key + ":" + value);
                    arrFlag = true;
                } else {
                    JSONArray value = jsonObject1.getJSONArray(key);
                    Log.i("Key:Value", "" + key + ":" + value);
                    arrFlag = false;
                }
            }
        }
```

It working perfectly.

You will get all keys and value over here.

Comment: Its not working for me.By using iterator keys it will select the random key in the second iteration. I got this exception Value 21 at main_id of type java.lang.String cannot be converted to JSONArray